# Will `pvcreate` refuse to create a PV out of a partition by default, if the partition has a filesystem which is not mounted?

Tags: lvm

https://www.thegeekdiary.com/lvm-error-cant-open-devsdx-exclusively-mounted-filesystem/ says

> LVM will only create a pv label on a device if it is not currently in
>   use. There are some of the other various causes for this issue, which
>   include’s:
>
> - The device for pvcreate has a **mounted** filesystem.
> - The device for pvcreate has a partition, but you are running pvcreate on the whole disk.

For the first case, it recommends a solution:

> If it is being used by a mount point which is currently mounted, umount it first.

If the device is a partition with an un-mounted filesystem, will `pvcreate` still refuse to create a PV out of the partition by default? (I can't test it out, because it is dangerous to test.)

I think that `pvcreate` should always refuse to create a PV out of a partition by default, if the partition contains a filesystem, regardless of whether the filesystem is mounted or not, to avoid data loss.

Thanks.

Comment: So…Why don't you just test it on a loop device? Or more  general, test everything in a VM…

Answer (score 1):

LVM will not refuse PV creation when on partition where is filesystem and partition is unmounted. At the end the responsibility for commands is yours. LVM (or any other program in Linux/UNIX) will refuse operation when this operation can interfere with the running OS. And as filesystem is not mounted it is not part of **running** OS